# $var::staticfunction() OK but $this->var::staticfunction() NOT. What's the rationale?

Tags: php, static

In PHP, a static member or function can be accessed so long as the class name is a valid object or a string. This is *mostly* true.  When the class name string is a property of an object, it can't be used directly. It must be copied to a simple variable before it can be used to access a static member. Here's an example:

```
class Foo {
  protected $otherclass='Bar'; //string!

  function out(){
    $class=$this->otherclass;
    echo $class::ALIAS;  //Where everyone knows your name.
  }

  function noout_err(){
    echo $this->otherclass::ALIAS; //syntax error, unexpected '::' 
  }
}

class Bar {
  const ALIAS='Where everyone knows your name.'
}
```

This quirk has bothered me for a while now. So I've been wondering:

- Is this a common limitation among OOP languages?
- Can someone familiar with the internals of PHP explain why `$this->classname::somefunction()` is not desirable syntax?

This isn't meant to provoke a storm of 'because php sux' comments. I'm well aware of the language's peculiarities. I'd just like to know if there is a reason for this one other than 'it just grew that way'.

Comment: There are two core limitations: 1) PHP uses a single pass compilation instead of an AST and 2) PHP uses different symbols for functions and variables. (Is $this->foo() a function call or an instance variable named foo of a closure?) These limitations are usually felt within the OO model, as it came later in PHP's life.

Comment: And anyone have any idea what to do if $otherClass is static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a limitation indeed and there's a reason for it:
The `::` scope operator has an higher precedence over `->` which means that:

```
$this->otherclass::ALIAS;
```

will be read as:

```
($this->(otherclass::ALIAS));
```

therefore triggering the error.

This is actually a feature that PHP inherited [probably](http://it.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) by C++.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Not really. Other "variable variables" features require disambiguation yet made it into the language. Allowing `{$this->otherclass}::ALIAS` would be sufficient.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: his explanation *does* explain why it doesn't work.  Why `{$this->otherclass}::ALIAS` isn't allowed is another question.

Comment: His explanation doesn't at all explain why this functionality isn't in the language. It only presents one possible type of syntax and why, given that the functionality isn't in the language, is it not valid. But that was really not the question. You might as well ask "why doesn't PHP support cake? `give-me-cake` yields a syntax error" and accept "give-me-cake isn't valid PHP syntax because of the hyphens and missing semicolon" as an answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, did you even bother reading my answer?

Comment: @Jeffrey: Yes, I read it thoroughly several times before downvoting it for being invalid. It suggests that if the order of precedence of operators were changed then this feature would magically be supported in the language, which is nonsense. It's a _false correlation_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, do I really have to state why you don't make any sense? Can't you just read your comment and get it yourself?

Comment: @Jeffrey: Erm. Why don't _you_ read my comment and get it yourself. Thanks for approaching this in a non-hostile manner; it's really very professional.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, you got me wrong. And I'm sorry for that. But "Can someone familiar with the internals of PHP explain why $this->classname::somefunction() is not desirable syntax?" seems that he want to know why does that syntax error happen. I've explained that quire clearly there. "But that was really not the question.", yes that was exactly the question, as stated by the author himself.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you may have some very good points but you have been coming across as dismissive and condescending. It makes it difficult to listen to you.

Comment: @dnagirl: Well, I am in fact neither. I propose reading my comments again with that in mind, without the prejudice that has evidently befallen your interpretation of my thorough and detailed analysis of this answer. Remember that you cannot detect emotion across the internet.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, also what you state in your answer that "there's no explicit reason for it" is just not true, and that is explained in my answer. It was not choose because is not intuitive enough, it was choose because PHP takes inspiration from C++ for its syntax and C++ have a certain operator precedence.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Oh, so you assert that the PHP devs, back in 1995, _deliberately_ arranged PHP's operator precedence so that this feature would be impossible? Despite the fact that OOP (and thus member-`static`) wasn't added until PHP 4? What nonsense! In fact, the operator precedence has _nothing to do_ with any reason that this feature is not in PHP, as I have already said. It simply was never necessary, never asked for, never designed, and never included. If it had been, a way would have been found to make it work, properly with disambiguating `{}` like in other such cases.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, the `->` and `::` operator were both added in PHP5 therefore they decided at that point which one had the precedence. And yes, when building a language, *I guess*, is necessary to define the precedence of each operator, otherwise how would you decide how to get the correct expression from an instruction? It's like saying that `+` and `*` has no precedence in math.

Comment: @Jeffrey: As you yourself indicated, the precedence of those operators was derived from C++. They didn't decide anything. Making the precedence different than in every other object-aware language just so that dnagirl could have her preferred variable variables static member access syntax was not on the table.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, PHP does not directly derives from C++. It's not a sublanguage of C++. It a language that just **took inspiration** from many languages **and** C++; so in theory they could have had decided whatever they wanted. But yeah that would have been a mistake. So what's your point now?

Comment: @Jeffrey: My point hasn't changed. Read both my answer and my first comment on yours to find out the truth. Have a nice day.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, you too.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can't do this, and there's no explicit reason for it. There's simply no syntax, messing up the grammar, to provide for this extreme edge case for which you've already demonstrated that there's a trivial workaround.

I'd hardly go so far as to call it a "limitation", and it's certainly no "quirk". PHP can't bake bread, either.

Really, if you see the code `$this->classname::somefunction()`, does it immediately make intuitive sense to you? Nah. It's *good* that you can't do this.