# PHP call method of class where class name is in field of other class

Tags: php, class, static-methods

I have a CodeIgniter php setup and enhanced it with RESTful capabilities.

I have the following structure

base.php (this is the base controller class

```
class Base {
    private $model
    public function __construct($model = false) {
        $this->model = $model . '_model';
        $this->load->model($this->model);
    ...
}
```

And then a controller which specifies a model

```
class Products extends Base {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('product');     
    }
}
```

The problem is as follows: in base.php I have functions for HTTP methods (get, post, put, delete), but I am not able to call a static method from the model like so:

```
public function get() {
    return $this->model::loadData();
}
```

If I assign `$this->model` to a local variable in `get()` it works, but it looks ugly to me.

So my question is: how can I call a static method of a class A given the class name in a member of class B without assigning it to a new local variable in methods of class B?

P.S.: I know CodeIgniter does not look like this, but the structure of it is irrelevant to my problem.

Comment: I think you can call static functions with the -> operator too.

Comment: When calling like that, it shows `Fatal error: Call to a member function loadData() on a non-object`

Comment: Sorry i thought you had an object in ->model. What do you have that works? What version of PHP do you use?

Comment: php -v:
PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 24 2012 17:45:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

In get() I have:
    $class = $this->model;
    return $class::load();

Comment: I don't think it can be done much simpler than that. PHP is odd like that, and it requires a variable to do this trick.. I thought you might be able to do something like ($this->model)::load(); but that just causes syntax error.

Comment: Also be aware that $class::doFoo() causes `unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` in older versions of php5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, assigning **$this->model** to a local variable like **$model** and then calling **$model::loadData()** works as expected.

The fact that the **$this->model::loadData()** call doesn't work might have to do we precedence between the **::** and **->** operators, but I can't say for sure as there's no reference to these in the official documentation.

> For operators of equal precedence, left associativity means that evaluation proceeds from left to right, and right associativity means the opposite. For operators of equal precedence that are non-associative those operators may not associate with themselves. So for example, the statement 1 < 2 > 1, is illegal in PHP. Whereas, the statement 1 <= 1 == 1 is not, because the T_IS_EQUAL operator has lesser precedence than the T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL operator.

from [PHP Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

I might be way off here, but from the behaviour of your code I'd say they're either the same precedence or **::** has a higher precedence than **->**, hence not usable together as you intended.

#### UPDATE

It confirms, the **::** operator has higher precedence that **->** therefore PHP interprets this:

```
$this->model::loadData();
```

as

```
($this->(model::loadData()));
```

Check the answer for the [$var::staticfunction() OK but $this->var::staticfunction() NOT. What's the rationale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814244/varstaticfunction-ok-but-this-varstaticfunction-not-whats-the-ratio) question.